# How do I add a canvas tag to my ocean id in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html5

I'm trying to create a "wack-a-mole" type of game. I've gotten all of the lines of code except in one area. Here is all of the code:

```
<!doctype html>
<title>Squid Smash!</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="monsterSmash.css">

<style type="text/css">
body {
background-image: url(squid.png);
background-size:1000px 600px;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
.ComicSansBlue {
font-family: Comic Sans MS;
font-size: 24px;
font-style: normal;
color: blue;
font-weight: 700;
text-align: left;
}
}
</style>

<body class="ComicSansBlue">
<img src="=SquidMonstersGame2.png" alt="Squid Smash"><p id="output"></p>
<div id="ocean"></div>

<script>

//--- The squidMonster object
var squidMonster =
{
//tilesheet source, size of each frame, and number of game columns
tileGraphic: "monsterTileSheet4.png",
size: 256,
columns: 3,

//The numbers of the animation frames and the starting frame
numberOfFrames: 5,
currentFrame: 0,

//Properties of the animation frames's x and y positions on the tile sheet.
//They're 0 when this object first loads
sourceX: 0,
sourceY: 0,

//A property to control the loop 
forward: true,

//States
hiding: 0,
leaping: 1,
strike: 2,
state: this.hiding,

//Properties needed to help reset the animation
timeToReset: 9,
resetCounter: 0,

//A property to store the random time
waitTime: undefined,

//A method to find a random animation time
findWaitTime: function()
{
this.waitTime = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 60); 
},

//The squidMonster's aniMate method
aniMate: function()
{ 
this.sourceX 
= Math.floor(this.currentFrame % this.columns) * this.size;
this.sourceY 
= Math.floor(this.currentFrame / this.columns) * this.size;

//Figure out the squidMonster's state
if(this.state !== this.strike)
{
if(this.waitTime > 0 || this.waitTime === undefined)
{
this.state = this.hiding;
}
else
{
this.state = this.leaping;
}
}

//Change the behaviour of the animation based on the state
switch(this.state)
{
case this.hiding:
this.currentFrame = 0;
this.waitTime--;
break;

case this.leaping:
//If the last frame has been reached, set forward to false
if(this.currentFrame === this.numberOfFrames)
{
this.forward = false;
}

//If the first frame has been reached, set forward to true
if(this.currentFrame === 0 && this.forward === false)
{
//Set forward to true, find a new waitTime,
//set the state to hiding and break the switch statement
this.forward = true;
this.findWaitTime();
this.state = this.hiding;
break;
}

//Add 1 to currentFrame if forward is true, subtract 1 if it's false
if(this.forward)
{
this.currentFrame++;
}
else
{
this.currentFrame--;
}
break;

case this.strike:
//Set the current frame to the last one on the tilesheet
//to display the explosion image
this.currentFrame = 6;

//Update the resetCounter by 1
this.resetCounter++;

//Reset the animation if the resetCounter equals the timeToReset
if(this.resetCounter === this.timeToReset)
{
this.state = this.hiding;
this.forward = true;
this.currentFrame = 0;
this.resetCounter = 0;
this.findWaitTime();
}
break;
}
}
};

//======================================================================
//======================== The gameTimer object ========================

var gameTimer =
{
time: 0,
interval: undefined,

begin: function()
{
var self = this;
this.interval = setInterval(function(){self.tick();}, 1000);
},
tick: function()
{
this.time--;
},
stop: function()
{
clearInterval(this.interval);
},
reset: function()
{
this.time = 0;
}
};

//=====================================================================
//--- Main program
//=====================================================================

//Load animation tile sheet
var tileGraphic = new Image();
tileGraphic.addEventListener("load", loadHandler, false);
tileGraphic.src = squidMonster.tileGraphic;

//The number of rows and columns and the size of each cell
var rows = 3;
var columns = 6;
var size = squidMonster.size;
var space = 10;

//Arrays for the squidMonsters, canvases and drawing surfaces
var squidMonsterObjects = [];
var squidMonsterCanvases = [];
var monsterDrawingSurfaces = [];

//Game variables
var squidMonsterSquishes = 0;

//Get a referene to the output
var output = document.querySelector("#output");

function loadHandler()
{ 
//Plot the grid of monsters
fillOcean();

//begin the game timer
gameTimer.time = 30;
gameTimer.begin();

//begin the animation loop
aniMate();
}

function fillOcean()
{ 
for(var row = 0; row < rows; row++) 
{ 
playSound('whaleOcean.mp3');
for(var column = 0; column < columns; column++) 
{ 

//Create a new squidMonster object, give it a random time, display its
//first frame and push it into an array
var newMonsterObject = Object.create(squidMonster);
newMonsterObject.findWaitTime();
squidMonsterObjects.push(newMonsterObject);
```

Here is where I'm having the problems (I put a * by the line):
I've created a canvas tag, I've created a var so I can use the div, but I don't know how to add the canvas tag to the ocean tag. As you can see I kind of start the line, because I think that's right (which if it isn't, please tell me). I would like to know what line or lines of code I need and why. I did try to look for answers, but couldn't find any so if anyone knows of a good article on the concept, that'd be appreciated as well as the lines of code to put in here.

```
//Create a canvas tag for each squidMonster, add it to the <div id="ocean"> tag,
//position it, then add a mousedown listener and push it into an array

var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var div = document.getElementByID('ocean');
*canvas.id =
canvas.style.position = "relative";
canvas.height = 256;
canvas.width = 256;
canvas.AddEventListener("mousedown", mousedownHandler, true);

//Create drawing surface. push it into the drawingSurfaces array
var drawingSurface = canvas.getContext("2d");
monsterDrawingSurfaces.push(drawingSurface);
}
}
}

function aniMate()
{ 
//Call aniMate every 120 milliseconds while the timer > 0.
if(gameTimer.time > 0)
{
setTimeout(aniMate, 120);
}

//Loop through all the monsters in the array, call aniMate method
for(var i = 0; i < squidMonsterObjects.length; i++)
{
aniMate();
}

//check for the end of the game
if(gameTimer.time === 0)
{
gameOver();
}

//Render the animation
render();
}

function gameOver()
{
//Stop the gameTimer
gameTimer.stop();

//Remove the mousedown event listeners from the
//canvas tags so that they can't be clicked
for(var i = 0; i < squidMonsterCanvases.length; i++)
{
var canvas = squidMonsterCanvases[i];
canvas.removeEventListener("mousedown", mousedownHandler, false);
}
}
function playSound(soundfile_ogg, soundfile_mp, soundfile_ma) {
if ("Audio" in window) {
var a = new Audio();
if (!!(a.canPlayType && a.canPlayType('audio/ogg; codecs="vorbis"')
.replace(/no/, '')))
a.src = soundfile_ogg;
else if (!!(a.canPlayType && a.canPlayType('audio/mpeg;').replace(/no/,
'')))
a.src = soundfile_mp;
else if (!!(a.canPlayType && a.canPlayType(
'audio/mp4; codecs="mp4a.40.2"').replace(/no/, '')))
a.src = soundfile_ma;
else
a.src = soundfile_mp;

a.autoplay = true;
return;
} else {
alert("Time almost up");
}
}
function mousedownHandler(event)
{
//Find out which canvas was clicked
var theCanvasThatWasClicked = event.target;

//Search squidMonsterCanvases array for a canvas that matches the clicked one
for(var i = 0; i < squidMonsterCanvases.length; i++)
{
if(squidMonsterCanvases[i] === theCanvasThatWasClicked)

{
var squidMonster = squidMonsterObjects[i]
if(squidMonster.state === squidMonster.leaping)
{
currentFrame = 6;
squidMonsterSquishes++;
playSound('explosion.mp3'); 
}
}
}
}

function render()
{
for(var i = 0; i < squidMonsterObjects.length; i++)
{ 
//Get reference to the current squidMonster and drawing surface
var squidMonster = squidMonsterObjects[i];
var drawingSurface = canvas.getContext("2d");

//Clear the current squidMonster's canvas
drawingSurface.clearRect(0, 0, size, size);

//Draw the squidMonster's current animation frame 
drawingSurface.drawImage
(
tileGraphic, 
squidMonster.sourceX, squidMonster.sourceY, size, size, 
0, 0, size, size
);
}

//Display the output
output.innerHTML 
= "<span class='ComicSansGreenLightYellow '> Squid Monsters Squished:</span>" + squidMonsterSquishes 
+ "<span class='ComicSansGreenLightYellow '>, Time left:</span>" + gameTimer.time; 
}
</script>
```

Comment: That's *349 lines* of code. Can we edit some out or is *all of it* important to the question? I'm not sure if this is what you're asking, but you can call [a DOM `Node`'s `appendChild` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.appendChild) to make one element a child of another. You might be looking for `div.appendChild(canvas)`.

Comment: I only provided the rest of the code for reference. I can leave it out if folks don't think it's necessary.

Comment: Yes, in the future only include as much code as is absolutely necessary. This much code turns people off to even reading the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what was wrong with my 8 lines of code for those of you who may be interested.

```
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var div = document.getElementById("ocean");
canvas.width = 256;
canvas.height = 256;
div.appendChild(canvas);
canvas.style.top = row*(256 + space) + "px";
canvas.style.left = column*(256 + space) + "px";
canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", mousedownHandler, false);
squidMonsterCanvases.push(canvas);
```

I had actually had all 8 of these lines at one point but was struggling and thought my code was wrong. Then I found out it wasn't working because my "addEventListener" had a capital A.

Comment: I noticed that after you posted this answer, but only because GameDev SE syntax-highlighted it. :-)